# website form to update persons leave dates

Tags: sql

I have a website with a form that should allow people to add multiple leave dates. Im trying to add more than one leave date to a specific person but cant get it to work. I have two tables volunteer which i have working where i can add new volunteers from the website and it updates in the sql database, just need the same for volunteer leave.

```
CREATE TABLE [VOLUNTEER](
[VOLUNTEER_ID] [int] identity (1,1) not null,
[FIRSTNAME] [nvarchar] (20) not null,
[LASTNAME] [nvarchar] (20) not null, 
[DATE_OF_BIRTH] [DATE] NOT NULL,
[PHONENUMBER] [nvarchar] (20) not null,
[ADDRESS] [NVARCHAR] (200) NOT NULL
);


  INSERT INTO [VOLUNTEER](
  [FIRSTNAME],[LASTNAME],[DATE_OF_BIRTH],[PHONENUMBER],[ADDRESS])

  VALUES
 ('Randolph','Spinks','1989/09/13','8486463',
  '16, Camesky Rd, Caol,    Fort William, PH33 7ER'),

 ('Pete','Cremer','1981/01/24','4178846',
 '1, Achintore Rd, Banavie, Fort William, PH33 7RE'),

 ('Nikia','Norsworthy','1974/06/17','9824814',
 '2, Seaview Terrace, Ballachulish, Fort William, PH33 6RG'),




 create table [LEAVE](
 [LEAVE_ID] [int] identity (1,1) not null,
 [VOLUNTEER_ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
 [FIRSTNAME] [nvarchar] (20) not null,
 [LASTNAME] [nvarchar] (20) not null, 
 [START_DATE] [DATE]  not null,
 [END_DATE] [DATE]  not null,
 );

   INSERT INTO [LEAVE]
  ([VOLUNTEER_ID],[FIRSTNAME],[LASTNAME],[START_DATE],[END_DATE])

  VALUES

  ('1','Randolph','Spinks','2016-08-20','2016-08-23'),
  ('2','Pete','Cremer','2016-07-20','2016-07-26'),
  ('3','Nikia','Norsworthy','2016-05-08','2016-06-01')

  GO
```

Below is the code i have been using in notepad. Im not sure wether the names should be just a drop down box as they are already registered volunteers. I also dont know if the volunteer id should be included which is a int not null foreign key field to link the two tables volunteer and leave together.

```
       <form name="submit" method="post" >


       <h2>Submit Leave</h2>

       <table border="0">

           <tr>
             <td>VOLUNTEER_ID</td>
             <td>
                <input type="INT" name="VOLUNTEER_ID" id="VOLUNTEER_ID"/>
             </td>
          </tr>

            <tr>

             <td>FIRSTNAME</td>
             <td>
                <select name="FIRSTNAME" id="FIRSTNAME">
                  <option value="Randolph  ">Randolph  </option>
                  <option value="Pete ">Pete </option>
                  <option value="Nikia ">Nikia </option>                          
                  </select>
             </td>
             </tr>


              <tr>

             <td>LASTNAME</td>
             <td>
                <select name="LASTNAME" id="LASTNAME">
                  <option value=" Spinks "> Spinks </option>
                  <option value=" Cremer"> Cremer</option>
                  <option value=" Norsworthy"> Norsworthy</option>
                  </select>
             </td>
             </tr>

        <tr>
             <td>START_DATE</td>
             <td>
                <input type="DATE" name="START_DATEDATE" id="START_DATE"/>
             </td>
          </tr>  

          <tr>
             <td>END_DATE</td>
             <td>
                <input type="DATE" name="END_DATEDATE" id="END_DATE"/>
             </td>
          </tr>  


          <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit"                 
             value="Submit Leave"/></td>

          </tr>
       </table>
```

Apoligies here is my php to link them both.

```
    <?php
    if( !empty( $_POST ) && isset( $_POST["VOLUNTEER_ID"],       
   $_POST["FIRSTNAME"], $_POST["LASTNAME"], $_POST["START_DATE"],   
   $_POST["END_DATE"] ) ) {

    /* 
        There is no point creating a db connection if a later condition fails
        so create the db conn after testing key variables are set
    */

    $server = "KATIE-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
    $options = array( "Database"=>"PROJECT2" );


    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $options );

    /* In production environment do not display actual errors! */
    if( !$conn ) die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ) );   


 $VOLUNTEER_ID = $_POST["VOLUNTEER_ID"];
    $FIRSTNAME = $_POST["FIRSTNAME"];
    $LASTNAME = $_POST["LASTNAME"];
    $START_DATE = $_POST["START_DATE"];
    $END_DATE = $_POST["END_DATE"];



    $sql = "INSERT INTO LEAVE
        ( [VOLUNTEER_ID],[FIRSTNAME], [LASTNAME], [START_DATE], [END_DATE] )
            VALUES
        ( ?,?,?,?,? )";

    $params=array(
     &$VOLUNTEER_ID,
        &$FIRSTNAME,
        &$LASTNAME,
        &$START_DATE,
        &$END_DATE

    );

    /* add the posted variables as an array here as the third arg */
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare( $conn, $sql, $params ) or die( 'Error querying MSSQL database' );
    if( $stmt ) sqlsrv_execute( $stmt );



/* debug post vars */           
} else { 
    echo 'Error::' . print_r( $_POST, true );
}
```

?>

Comment: I don't see any actual code which would interact with your database.

Comment: In fact as Tim said, here we see only how tables are composed, your HTML but no interaction between HTML and the DBs.
First thing you should do is too choose a web language like PHP and use it to to some GET-POST actions. http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-insert-query.php 

In the link there is an example for MySQL if you can say us the DB you're using we can be more specific for your use case.

Comment: Sorry forgot to put that in. Just edited the above, hope this helps